# i'm getting the error in the paypal integration

Tags: ios, paypal

i'm getting the error in the paypal integration.i download the sdk from this link [paypal SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK)
but i'm getting this linker errors
[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: You need to add a new more frameworks to your project such as CoreLocation and AudioToolbox. See the instructions for paypal.

Answer (score 0):

1.Add necessary frameworks and

2.goto target->Build Setting in that

2.1.add -lc++ -ObjC to Other Linker Flags.

2.2.set YES in Enable Modules (C and Objective-C).

2.3.set YES in Link Frameworks Automatically.

Finally clean &build your project.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following frameworks

1)Security.framework

2)libxml2.dylib

3)libz.1.2.5.dylib